# Python How can I get the version number from a .whl file

Tags: python, python-wheel

Because of some custom logging I would like to get the version number from a wheel file.

I could of course just parse the filename, but my guess is there would be a better way to do this.

Comment: What's wrong with parsing the file name? But anyway... a wheel file is a zip archive. You can read about the format in [PEP-0427](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#file-format).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use [pkginfo](https://pythonhosted.org/pkginfo/distributions.html#introspecting-wheels) e.g.

```
from pkginfo import Wheel

w = Wheel(r'C:\path\to\package.whl')

print(w.version)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I've done for now is:

Get the package info and put it into a `dict`:

```
import os

def get_package_info():
    info_dict = {}
    with open(os.path.join(glob.glob("./*.egg-info")[0], "PKG-INFO"), "r") as info:
        for i in info:
            i = i.split(":")
            info_dict[i[0].strip()] = i[1].strip()

    return info_dict

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_package_info())
```

Now I can get the Version from this dictionary.

If someone does have a better approach at this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

A simple parsing of the wheel's filename should be enough:

```
>>> 'torch-1.8.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl'.split('-')[1]
'1.8.1'
```

If you want to be more sophisticated, you can also use [wheel-filename](https://pypi.org/project/wheel-filename) to do this parsing for you:

```
>>> from wheel_filename import parse_wheel_filename
>>> pwf = parse_wheel_filename('pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl')
>>> pwf.version
'18.0'
```

If you just need to compute it quickly for a single package, you can use this codepen page I created, to get version and more details from a wheel's filename: https://codepen.io/chaitan94/full/mdWEeBp