# Pygame 1.9.4. Installation Trouble

Tags: python, pygame

Using Windows/Python 3.7 and Pygame 1.9.4 is already installed, except I exited out of the terminal and can't find the version name to finish the installation.

According to the book I'm following, I need to finish by typing in:
"python -m pip install --user pygame-[version name].whl"

I can't find the version name anywhere online. I remember it started with "pygame-18.0"

Edit: It works now! It was installed the whole time. Still not sure what the book wants me to do with the whl file thing, but if that raises problems, I'll just restart the whole process again. Thank you!

Comment: If pygame is already installed, then what are you trying to do? `python -m pip install --user pygame` will install the most recent pygame version. You don't have to specify the version number.

Comment: The book said that because the file is not exe, I needed to type the quoted line to finish the installment process.

Comment: Just enter `python -m pip install --user pygame` to install pygame, you don't have to do anything else. In Windows you can also enter `py -3.7 -m pip install --user pygame` to specify the Python version for which you want to install pygame. Then start the Python interpreter and enter `import pygame` to see if it is installed (if something's wrong, an error message will be printed).

Comment: OHHHHHH
.......
Thank you! I didn't understand what the book was saying.

Answer (score 0):

try pip3/pip install pygame
now the latest version of pygame is "pygame-1.9.4"

Comment: The terminal says it's already installed. Just need to see how to finish the process and run the program. Do you know how to get the whl version name of pygame 1.9.4?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/42019184/10283972 hopes can help you